# ClickHouse Get data in 7 days fixed intervals(not calendar intervals)

Tags: clickhouse

How can I get data in 7 days fixed intervals buckets in ClickHouse?
I tried date functions that are related to week(toStartOfWeek, ...) but these functions work almost with calendar intervals, and not fixed intervals. I've also tried `interval` operator, but data is not counted based on my own criteria. This is how I wrote my query:

```
select toStartOfWeek(datefield2) + interval 5 day,
       toStartOfWeek(datefield1) + interval 5 day,
       count(distinct user_id) as unique_users
from my_db.my_table 
where (datefield1 >= '2022-04-01 00:00:00' AND datefield1 <= '2022-05-30 23:59:59')
  and (datefield2 >= '2022-04-01 00:00:00' and datefield2 <= '2022-05-30 23:59:59')
group by toStartOfWeek(datefield2) , toStartOfWeek(datefield1)
order by toStartOfWeek(datefield2), toStartOfWeek(datefield1)
limit 100 offset 0;
```

without `interval`, buckets start from 2022-03-27 by default(which is Sunday):

| datefield2 | datefield1 | unique_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-03-27 | 10000 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-04-03 | 50000 |
| 2022-03-27 | 2022-04-10 | 40000 |

When I added `interval`, buckets start from 2022-04-01(the date I want) but the data count is the same. It means that it is still counting data based on the calendar, and not based on my interval:

| datefield2 | datefield1 | unique_users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-01 | 10000 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-08 | 50000 |
| 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-15 | 40000 |

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: All dates are stored as epoch timestamps in seconds, so you can maybe convert to a UInt32 field and bucket by 86400 * 7 seconds?  (This is what the ClickHouse Grafana plugins do)

Comment: Why do you have datefield1 and datefield2 ?

Comment: @DennyCrane One for creation time and the other for updated time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toStartOfInterval [1](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/#tostartofintervaltime_or_data-interval-x-unit--time_zone) instead

```
select toStartOfInterval(datefield2, interval 5 day),
   toStartOfInterval(datefield1, interval 5 day),
   count(distinct user_id) as unique_users
 from my_db.my_table 
 where (datefield1 >= '2022-04-01 00:00:00' AND datefield1 <= '2022-05-30 23:59:59')
     and (datefield2 >= '2022-04-01 00:00:00' and datefield2 <= '2022-05-30 23:59:59')
 group by 1,2
 order by 1,2
 limit 100 offset 0;
```